# Show that the transformation $w=\frac{2z+3}{z-4}$ maps the circle $x^2+y^2-4x=0$ onto the straight line $4u+3=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, absolute-value, conformal-geometry

**Question:**

> Show that the transformation $w=\frac{2z+3}{z-4}$ maps the circle $x^2+y^2-4x=0$ onto the straight line $4u+3=0$.

**My try:**
$$\begin{align}\\
&x^2+y^2-4x=0\\
&\implies (x-2)^2+y^2=4\\
&\implies |z-2|=2\\
\end{align}\\
$$
Now, $w=\frac{2z+3}{z-4}$
$$\begin{align}\\
&\frac w2=\frac{2z+3}{2z-8}\\
&\implies\require{cancel}\frac{w}{w-2}=\frac{2z+3}{\cancel{2z}+3-\cancel{2z}+8}\\
&\implies\frac{w}{w-2}=\frac{2z+3}{11}\\
&\implies\frac{2z}{11}=\frac{w}{w-2}-\frac{3}{11}\\
&\implies\frac{2z}{\cancel{11}}=\frac{8w+6}{\cancel{11}(w-2)}\\
&\implies z=\frac{4w+3}{w-2}\\
&\implies z-2=\frac{2w+7}{w-2}\\
\end{align}\\
$$
$$\therefore\left|\frac{2w+7}{w-2}\right|=2\\
\implies 2w+7=2w-4
$$
Now, what to do? Where is my fault? Or how to do it? Is there any other possible ways?

Comment: Your fault is taking away the modulus signs in the last line.  Consider looking where $3$ points on the circle get mapped to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't replace modulus like that in the last line ( because complex numbers with equal magnitude may not be actually equal. For e.g., $2i$ and $-2i$ have magnitude $2$ but aren't equal.)

Use $w = u+iv$

So, $|2(u+iv)+7| = 2|(u+iv)-2|$

Evaluating and squaring both sides,
$\Rightarrow (2u+7)^2 + 4v^2 = 4(u-2)^2 + 4v^2 $

$\Rightarrow 4u^2 + 28u +49  = 4u^2 - 16u + 16 $

$\Rightarrow 44u + 33 = 0 $

$\Rightarrow 4u +3 =0 $

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

[Ak19](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/668124/ak19) answered what I would have answered before I got to it, so here's another possible way of how to do it.  These transformations map generalized circles to generalized circles; a generalized circle is either a circle or a line.  This particular transformation maps the point $z=0$ on the given circle to $w=-\frac34$, the point $z=2+2i$ on the given circle to $-\frac34-\frac{11}4i$, and the point $z=2-2i$ on the given circle to $-\frac34+\frac{11}4i$, so we can see that it maps the circle to the line $u=-\frac34$.

Comment: This is a [Moebius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Preservation_of_angles_and_generalized_circles)

Comment: One thing that i couldn't understand was that how you are getting that $z=2+2i$ maps to $-\frac 34-\frac{11}{4}i$ or $z=2-2i$ to $-\frac 34+\frac{11}{4}i$? Can you please explain this?

Comment: Just plug $z=2\pm 2i$ in to the formula for $w$; you could then simplify by multiplying top and bottom of the fraction by the complex conjugate of the bottom; note that $w$ for $2-2i$ is the conjugate of $w$ for $2+2i$

Comment: Okay, now I get it. Nice explanation 

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to showing that $4w+3$ is pure imaginary i.e. $\arg(4w+3)=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Since $0$ and $4$ are end points of the circle diameter and $4w+3=11\frac{z-0}{z-4}$, then $\arg(4w+3)=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$.